# How to delete listview item without dismissible

Tags: flutter

I have a list of listTiles each with text and a button beside it to remove the tile. If the button is pressed the user confirms they want to delete it and the tile is removed. Previously I used a dismissible widget which took a key, but in this case how would I associate the item in the list with the tile I need to remove.

**Code** (Ignore onTap(), at the bottom the flatButtons are used as the prompt):

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: subGoals.length,
  itemBuilder: (context,index){
    return Card(
      color: Colors.grey[500],
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: (){
          //should make new list with the title of the ListTile's text
        },
        title: Text(subGoals[index],
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 35),
        ),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          color: Colors.white,
          splashColor: Colors.red[600], 
          onPressed: (){
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context){
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Center(child: Text("Delete List?", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
                  content: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text("Yes", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
                        onPressed: (){
                          if(true){
                             //removeTile method goes here
                          }
                        }
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text("No", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
                        onPressed: (){
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }
                      ),
```

Comment: Are you not using some sort of `List` of items to generate your `ListTile`s inside your `ListView`?

Comment: Yes I am, the part I'm confused about is how would the program know which index of the list I was clicking on when I pressed the button. Is there something I can access that ties the button to the rest of the tile / index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly from the question and comment, then you should have a method that you call from your `ListTile` to remove the item from your item `List`. You should be passing the `index` generated by your `ListView` to that method and using it to remove the item from the list from the matching position with the index. Then you use `setState()` to make sure your list is re-rendered on your ListView.

If you don't have this method and you need help writing it, please share more of your code and comment, and I will update this answer.

Comment: I understand your method and will try to implement it, when I click the button beside each tile is an index produced? That's the only part I'm missing. What distinguishes the 3rd tiles button click as opposed to the second. Once I can retrieve the index of the tile based on the button click I can pass it onto the removeTile method

Comment: You can use the index that your ListView builder provides you here `itemBuilder: (context,index){`.

Comment: Oh I see so the itembuilder handles the index dynamically when I click on the button. Thank you I'll try implementing this

Comment: can u please update your code how u did that? i am facing the same problem.

Comment: @JoãoSoares can u please update your answer with the code, i need it